# Angular2-mentions - How I can add URL link to mentioned user from angular2-mentions in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

How to add URL RouterLink to @mention user using angular2-mentions.

My Code is:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" [mention]="contactNames" [mentionConfig]="{triggerChar:'@',maxItems:10}" class="form-control input-underline input-lg baselg" id=""  maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter a conversation title(Max 100 characters)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="postText"> 
</div>
```

How to add this one:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/URL']" [queryParams]="{id:post?.userId}">{{contactNames}}</a>
```

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finale I did it using Pipe.

HTML:

```
<h4 class="post-sub-heading" [innerHTML]="post.shrtMessage | UserLink : {users: post.mentionedUsers, path: '/dentistpublicprofile'} | GeneralLink"> </h4>

<input type="text" [mention]="contactNames" [mentionConfig]="{triggerChar:'@',maxItems:10, labelKey:'name',format:'[@]'}" class="form-control input-underline input-lg baselg" id=""  maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter a conversation title(Max 100 characters)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="postText">
```

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'UserLink'
})
export class UserLinkPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args: { path: string, users: { name: string, id: string }[] }): any {
        args.users.forEach(mentionedUser => {
            const mentionedName = '@' + mentionedUser.name;
            const regx = new RegExp(mentionedName, 'g')
            value = value.replace(regx, (url: string) => {
                return `<a href="${args.path}?id=${mentionedUser.id}">${mentionedName}</a>`;
            })
        })
        return value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ts :

```
usersToMentions = [];
 mentionConfig = {
    mentionSelect: this.onMentionSelect,
    triggerChar: '@',
    maxItems: 10,
    labelKey: 'username',
  };

 onMentionSelect(selection): string {
    return `@${selection.username}`;
  }

 async detectUsersToBeMentioned() {
    const pattern = /\B@[a-z0-9_-]+/gi;
    const mentioned = this.textValue.match(pattern);
    if (!mentioned) return;
    else {
      let toFound = mentioned[mentioned.length - 1];
      const toAdd = await this.userService
        .getWithUsername(toFound.substring(1).toLowerCase())
        .toPromise();
      this.usersToMentions = [...this.usersToMentions, ...toAdd];
      this.usersToMentions = [
        ...new Map(
          this.usersToMentions.map((item) => [item['username'], item])
        ).values(),
      ];
    }
  }
```

in HTML you can create an input and use the mention with a template (add a link if you want) :

```
 <textarea
      [(ngModel)]="textValue"
      #replyInput
      (ngModelChange)="detectUsersToBeMentioned()"
      [mention]="usersToMentions"
      [mentionConfig]="mentionConfig"
      [mentionListTemplate]="mentionListTemplate"
      rows="1"
></textarea>

<!-- Mention template -->
<ng-template #mentionListTemplate let-item="item">
  <img class="avatar-30 rounded-circle" src="{{ item.pictureProfile }}" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  &nbsp;
  <span>@{{ item.username }}</span>
</ng-template>
```